# Changing space and width in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, browser, width

I have this table which has some data (`input` & `select` etc...), When any option is not selected, the spacing is correct in all browsers, but when I click on the `select` the spacing will be changed only in `Safari` and `Chrome` but it won't change in `Firefox`.

**Chrome BEFORE clicking on `Select`**

[image: before]

**Chrome AFTER clicking on `Select`**

[image]

**Firefox BEFORE&AFTER clicking on `Select`**

[image]

I did not include any code because it works fine in `Firefox`, and I thought maybe it's some css issue regarding browsers which I should put in my `styles`, but if needed I will also put my codes.

**UPDATE**

I added also the codes:
[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41kauv5b/)

```css
.rTableCell,
.rTableHead {
  xfloat: left;
  height: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px 3%;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 120%;
  display: table-cell;
}
.rTableCellId {
  width: 52px;
}
.rTableCellVal {
  width: 90px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="rTable">
  <div class="rTableRow" style="color:#797979">
    <div class="rTableCell rTableCellId ndLabel">835</div>
    <div class="rTableCell ndLabel" style="width:240px;">Visits on the website that end with the purchase</div>
    <div class="rTableCell ndLabel" style="width:160px;">LP thank you</div>

    <div class="rTableCell rTableCellSrc ndLabel">GA</div>

    <div class="rTableCell rTableCellUrlLoc" style="width:180px">
      <input id="campaignStructureList0.dataSourceModelList0.urlLocation" name="campaignStructureList[0].dataSourceModelList[0].urlLocation" style="width: 145px;" class="ndInbox" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:7px; width: 150px" class="rTableCell rTableCellVal">
      <select id="campaignGoalId" name="campaignStructureList[0].dataSourceModelList[0].goalId" style="width:100%">
        <option value="">--- Select1 ---</option>
        <option value="">--- Select2 ---</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Apparently the with of the dropped select is wider than when the select is not dropped down. I'm not sure what to do, other than, as a workaround, to make sure the select itself is as wide as the contents of iots widest option.

Comment: @MrLister I also changed the options length but it still has this problem.

Comment: Hm. Another problem seems to be that the width doesn't snap back to the original after you close the select. Not sure if there are any solutions.

Comment: @MrLister YES ! also that one is another issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to set the select's containing div to `position:relative;`, and the select itself to `position: absolute;` That takes it out of the flow and thus prevents the resizing of elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.rTableCell,
.rTableHead {
  xfloat: left;
  height: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px 3%;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 120%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.rTableCellId {
  width: 52px;
}

.rTableCellVal {
  width: 90px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.rTableCell {position: relative;}
.rTableCell select {position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 12px;}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="rTable">
  <div class="rTableRow" style="color:#797979">
    <div class="rTableCell rTableCellId ndLabel">835</div>
    <div class="rTableCell ndLabel" style="width:240px;">Visits on the website that end with the purchase</div>
    <div class="rTableCell ndLabel" style="width:160px;">LP thank you</div>

    <div class="rTableCell rTableCellSrc ndLabel">GA</div>

    <div class="rTableCell rTableCellUrlLoc" style="width:180px">
      <input id="campaignStructureList0.dataSourceModelList0.urlLocation" name="campaignStructureList[0].dataSourceModelList[0].urlLocation" style="width: 145px;" class="ndInbox" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:7px; width: 150px; " class="rTableCell rTableCellVal">
      <select id="campaignGoalId" name="campaignStructureList[0].dataSourceModelList[0].goalId" >
        <option value="">--- Select1 ---</option>
        <option value="">--- Select2 ---</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good one, it helped, let me see how it looks in the project.

Comment: Ah, this one is more elegant than mine, as it doesn't require JavaScript.

Comment: Admittedly, the positioning becomes an issue, and gets a little messy, but that can be overcome.

Answer (score 1):

A bit hackish, but if you're not opposed to using a little JavaScript, you can drop down the select on load and immediately close it back up.

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var sel = document.getElementById('campaignGoalId');
  sel.size=sel.options.length;
  sel.size = 1;
}
```

```css
.rTableCell,
.rTableHead {
  xfloat: left;
  height: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px 3%;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 120%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.rTableCellId {
  width: 52px;
}

.rTableCellVal {
  width: 90px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="rTable">
  <div class="rTableRow" style="color:#797979">
    <div class="rTableCell rTableCellId ndLabel">835</div>
    <div class="rTableCell ndLabel" style="width:240px;">Visits on the website that end with the purchase</div>
    <div class="rTableCell ndLabel" style="width:160px;">LP thank you</div>

    <div class="rTableCell rTableCellSrc ndLabel">GA</div>

    <div class="rTableCell rTableCellUrlLoc" style="width:180px">
      <input id="campaignStructureList0.dataSourceModelList0.urlLocation" name="campaignStructureList[0].dataSourceModelList[0].urlLocation" style="width: 145px;" class="ndInbox" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:7px; width: 150px" class="rTableCell rTableCellVal">
      <select id="campaignGoalId" name="campaignStructureList[0].dataSourceModelList[0].goalId" style="width:100%">
        <option value="">--- Select1 ---</option>
        <option value="">--- Select2 ---</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```